# The word Bonistics

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Does the word `Bonistics` really exist in English language? I could **not** find it in dictionaries but the internet search responses a lot with this word. It is about the papered money against the `Numismatics` - the metal coins.
If no, how is it called in English?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As Alice once exclaimed, ["Curiouser and curiouser!"](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/714245-curiouser-and-curiouser-cried-alice-she-was-so-much-surprised)

Sure enough, I couldn't find it in a dictionary, either. [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=bonistic*&ls=a) can't find it in any of the dictionaries it searches. [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/bonistics) tells me it can't be used in the game of Scrabble, even though it's been looked up more than six dozen times. It can't be found in lists of rare in obscure words found in [The Phrontistery](http://phrontistery.info/b.html). Even the OED – yes, *that* OED – said, "Nada":

[image]

And yet:

- It's used as a category on image websites like [CanStockPhoto](http://www.canstockphoto.com/images-photos/bonistics.html), [Fotosearch](http://www.fotosearch.com/photos-images/bonistics.html), and [Shutterstock](http://www.shutterstock.com/s/bonistics/search.html)
- It's found on the webpages of what appears to be a [reputable museum](http://www.saaremaamuuseum.ee/en/to-researchers/collections-of-saaremaa-museum/numismatics-and-bonistics/)
- It's referenced as a novel word on coin collecting [websites](http://www.coinbooks.org/esylum_v09n07a07.html) and [discussion forums](http://www.worldofcoins.eu/forum/index.php?topic=8291.0)
- When I just looked up "bonistics" on the auction site eBay, I got a hit in their "Paper Money" section

A couple websites postulated that it might be a borrowed Russian word, since so many hits seem to also reference Eastern European currencies. That's what happened to me as well:

[image]

So, getting back to your question: What makes a word an "English" word? That gets debated over at ELU every [now](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74605) and [then](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68169).

My ELL answer would be: It's a word that's recognizable by search engines, but very few native speakers will have heard of it. I can't remember running across it before. As one person wrote on that discussion thread, you'd be more readily understood if you said *banknote collecting*.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see online, "bonistics" is a loanword from Russian, and is used almost exclusively by Russian speakers and speakers of other Eastern European languages.  It does not seem to have been fully adopted into English yet, since it is not in dictionaries.

In English, the word "numismatics" covers both the study of coins and the study of paper money:

> nu·mis·mat·ics 
>   : the study or act of collecting of coins, paper money, and medals

(http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/numismatics)

Comment: Yes I understand that in Russian and some closest territories, like East European countries and/or some former USSR republics the separate word `bonistics` was appeared for study of banknotes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is an English language word:  Notaphily.
It is not widely used, but it does get used, and you will find it in dictionaries.
Not the case for "bonistics," which as mentioned earlier, comes from Russian (and other Slavic languages).
The term "numismatics" technically covers coins and banknotes (as well as items such as travelers checks, postal notes, money orders, etc.), but 99% of the time, it means coins.
You can also say "banknote collecting" or "paper money collecting" or "paper currency collecting" ... the latter two are becoming technically inaccurate since a growing number of banknotes are, in fact, printed on polymer (e.g. Canada, Australia, Singapore, New Zealand and many other nations).

And technically not all "paper money" (or "polymer notes") is, in fact, a banknote.  There is "emergency money" (Notgeld), there is "scrip" and other forms.  There are "test notes" and "specimens" and "proofs" and "essays" which never had, nor intended to have, any monetary function.  So consider the definitions to be "hazy."

Then you have advertising money which looks like a banknote, or propaganda money that looks like banknotes but contains propaganda messages and gets air-dropped on enemy forces, or you have "fantasy" money which is privately prepared, or you have "hell notes" which are fake money burned at funerals, and other variants.  Most banknote collectors will collect some subset of all of these.  Then you have checks, traveler's checks, lottery tickets, postal orders, postal notes, money orders, bills of exchange, traveling letters of credit and various other forms of financial instruments.

Finally you have stocks and bonds.  These at least have their own word for collecting:  Scripophily

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the term "bonistics", and apparently the spell checker in this "Your Answer" text box is not familiar with it either.  (This spell checker is surprisingly good.)

You might want to look for "rare coin dealers" (in other words, dealers that sell to "numismatists").  Many of them deal in "rare" or "collectible" bills, notes, certificates, and currencies.

The American websites [rarecurrency.com](http://www.rarecurrency.com/) and [Bellevue Rare Coins](http://www.wscbrc.com/) do not mention any one-word terms for collecting paper currencies, whereas the American website [rarecoinandstamp.com](http://www.rarecoinandstamp.com/) does mention the terms "numismatic" (for collecting coins) and "philatelic" (for collecting stamps).

Comment: Looks like `numismatics` covers both coins and paper money. There is not the separate word for study of banknotes in English. Thanks.